# Regular expression find and replace Notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have text like the following :

`<p class="field">[text text1 "text2"] </p>`

which i want to get text1 and text2 and replace them in the below text

`<p>[text text1 text2] <br/></p>`

How can i do that ?

Comment: And why don't you just replace (ctrl+h) `] </p>` with `] <br/></p>` and `<p class="field">` with `<p>`?

Comment: because the file to too large and i want to get the word and replace it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Untested, but I think this should do it.

I'm assuming the *exact* formatting, no room for more or less spaces anywhere. And that `text`, `text1` and `text2` can be anything.

Replace:

```
<p class="field">\[([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) "([^"]+)"\] </p>
```

with:

```
<p>\[\1 \2 \3\] <br/></p>
```

**Explanation:**

You may want to consider replacing the space characters in Replace with `\s` (white-space) for a more generic solution.

`\[` and `\]` - escaped `[` and `]`
`[^ ]` - not a space
`[^ ]+` - one or more characters that aren't spaces
`[^"]` - not a `"`
`[^"]+` - one or more characters that aren't `"`
`\1` - gives the string that corresponds to the first thing in brackets (i.e. `([^ ]+)`)
`\2` - gives the string that corresponds to the second thing in brackets (i.e. `([^ ]+)`)
`\3` - gives the string that corresponds to the third thing in brackets (i.e. `([^"]+)`)

Comment: `*` is zero or more, not one or more

Comment: @m4573r Yes, thanks. I know, I just keep typing it wrong all the time for some reason. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Search `<p class="field">\[(\S+ \S+) "(\S+)"\] </p>`, and replace with `<p>[\1 \2] <br/></p>`

Comment: It should be either `(\S+ \S+) "(\S+)"` to `\1 \2`, or `(\S+) (\S+) "(\S+)"` to `\1 \2 \3`.